# Angular: Replacing environment.ts with configuration specific files with ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular app which uses `environment.ts` file to set stuff like urls of servers.

I know that I can use **build configurations** specified in `angular.json` to replace files at build time, e.g. replace `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.

I would like something similar with `ng serve`, e.g. launching

```
ng serve --configuration=production
```

and having `environment.prod.ts` replacing `environment.ts`.

I this possible? Are there better ways to drive with command lines parameters which settings are used in `ng serve`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The one you say, `ng serve --configuration=production` actually replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`. It is already defined in Angular.

In case you want to have another replacements (i.e., more files replaced) depending on configuration, go to you `angular.json` and follow the structure:

1. Create a new configuration name under `build`:`configurations`
2. Fill in the `fileReplacements` array with your files to be replaced
3. Under `serve`:`configurations` create a new tag, and reference to the one you just created.
4. Launch serve, like: `ng serve --c=configuration-name` (note that `--c` is the same as `--configuration`)

#### Example:

```json
{
  . . .
  "projects": {
    "your-project-name": {
      . . .
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          . . .
          "options": { . . . },
          "configurations": {
            "production": { . . .  },
            "configuration-you-want-to-create": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/path-to-file.original",
                  "with": "src/path-to-file.tobereplaced"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/other-path-to-file.original",
                  "with": "src/other-path-to-file.tobereplaced"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          . . .
          "options": {. . .},
          "configurations": {
            "production": { . . .},
            "configuration-you-want-to-create": {
              "browserTarget": "your-project-name:build:configuration-you-want-to-create"
            }
          }
        },
        . . .
      }
    }},
  . . .
}
```

Comment: Great answer! 

Comment: one quick question here:  When using fileReplacement, what are the rules to follow? I mean on serve, in my case, i get some schema validation failing, and I cant seems to find any real life example (except that environement one). Nor can I find any infos on what is allowed and what is not here...

Comment: @Minus Not really sure what your issue is. Angular docs are scarce on fille replacements (https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements). Maybe sombre bracket nesting issue? Any other thant that, not info on name conventions (if thats your issue, try with only letters).

Comment: @Sergio, the issue was actually filename's extention missing... The validation error message lead me off tracks... and took me too much time to figure out! :(

Comment: Great answer I've seen about this question and It worked. Thanks.